# In Apache Spark, how to push data from an executor to its own table?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, teradata

This is for a specific use case - we are trying to stream data from Apache Kafka to Teradata DB using Spark Streaming. We have been using JDBC drivers to load into Teradata. 
We increased the number of executors and started noticing blocking on Teradata's end. We could see that each executor was trying to load data into the table, thereby blocking another executor's load.
We eventually did a repartition, so that only 1 executor writes to the table. 
I was wondering if we could get an executor to write to its own table.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how Teradata DB works. Maybe you can push each partition to its own table?

Comment: Ah! that is something I will try! just to confirm would it be possible that partition #1 would be present in Executor #1 AND Executor #2 ? Wouldn't that create a problem if try inserting the same record to same table from 2 different executors ?

Comment: That's possible, e.g., when speculation is enabled, or network partition. You need to make sure your codes are idempotent. However, since network partition rarely happens, and speculation is disabled by default, it won't affect the performance.